# How to validate the variable value with regex in ansible

Tags: ansible, regex

how to  validate the variable value using regex in ansible

```
var:
  DeviceName: "xxxxx-ax34tas1.xxxint.pngxx.abc.com"

- name: valdiate switchname
      set_fact:
        switchname: "{{'false' if DeviceName | regex_match('\\S+(ias|pas|tas|sps)\\S+(mfg|kssm|png|cd|ss|ch|ra|cr)\\S+') else 'true'}}"
```

it should come as false but i dont know why it is coming true

Comment: Your code doesn't look like valid YAML. You need to fix the formatting.

Comment: ... and "valdiate", if that's what it really says in your config.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the documentation [there is no filter regex_match](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions), at least as of v2.9 and later.

> *it should come as `false` but I dont know why it is coming `true`*

Since a simple test construct

```
var:
  DeviceName: "switch.example.com"

- name: Valdiate device name
  set_fact:
    switchname: "{{'false' if DeviceName | regex_search('switch') else 'true'}}"
```

delivers `true` for a `switch` and `false` for a `server` it seems to be your regular expression.

After I've found [Use Jinja match filter instead of regex_match](https://opendev.org/opendev/system-config/commit/3e139891be0f5130bfdb23a5a49bd04448f870f6)

> [DEPRECATION WARNING]: Using tests as filters is deprecated. Instead
> of using `result|match` use `result is match`. This feature will be
> removed in version 2.9.

I've tested with

```
var:
  DeviceName: "switch.example.com"

- name: Valdiate device name
  set_fact:
    switchname: "{{ DeviceName is match ('server*') }}"
```

and found it also working properly. As of Ansible 2.9 this should be the preferred solution.